# Swift: Array over custom class does not initialize

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an array over objects from a custom class. I declare the class like this:

```
class myClass{
    var a = 0
}
```

and use it in an SpriteKit iOS base project in the `didMoveToView` function:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    var array = [myClass]()
    var mc = myClass()
    mc.a = 12
    array.append(mc)
```

After this few lines, the array still is empty.

The debugger shows that array is not initialized. There is no "{}" after the `declaration/initialization` command.
If I change the array declaration to `[Int]`, everything will be fine.

Can anybody reproduce this strange behavior or give me a hint?

**EDIT 1:**

It works as expected in a playground.

**EDIT 2:**

Error is when I compile and run it on iPhone 5 Simulator. On iPhone 6 it works as expected.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this completely.
It seems like this is a bug with the simulator.
Even inheriting from NSObject doesn't change anything.

Comment: Log it with Apple as a bug https://bugreport.apple.com